A circle is inscribed in a triangle, with three other circles in the corner regions. The radii are integers. Possible values of the largest radius?
Consider four circles with integer radii inscribed in a triangle as shown.

That is, a circle with integer radius $R$ is inscribed in a triangle, and three other circles with integer radii $a,b,c$ are each tangent to the large circle and two sides of the triangle.

Given an arbitrary positive integer, how can we determine if it is a possible value of $R$?

(As an analogy, here is a similar question, and its answer: Given an arbitrary positive integer, how can we determine if it is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with integer side lengths? The answer is by checking if it has a prime factor of the form $4k+1$.)
My attempt
It turns out that $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$.
So we require $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ and $R>\max(a,b,c)$ where $R, a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.
If we temporarily relax the requirement that $R>\max(a,b,c)$, then it can be shown that $R$ can be any positive integer except $1,2,4$, as follows (but I'm not sure if this is useful). $R$ can be any odd number greater than $1$, because if $a=1,\space b=1,\space c=n^2$, then $R=2n+1$. As @Zoe Allen noted in the comments, if $a,b,c$ give $R$, then $2a,2b,2c$ give $2R$, so $R$ can be $2^k(2n+1)$, so it only remains to consider the powers of $2$. As @John Omielan noted, if $a=1,\space b=4,\space c=4$ then $R=8$, so $R$ can be any power of $2$ larger than $4$. Clearly $R$ cannot equal $2$. It is easy to show that $R$ cannot equal $4$ (if $R\le 4$ then at least two of $a,b,c,$ must equal $1$, but then the third cannot make $R=4$). So $R$ can be any positive integer except $1,2,4$.
But with the requirement that $R>\max(a,b,c)$, there are many other numbers that cannot be $R$ values. As @Will Jagy noted, the numbers below $100$ that cannot be $R$ values are $1,2,4,7,13,14,17,23,28,34,37,43,46,49,53,67,73,97,98$. (As an example, $R=11$ is not on this list because $11=\sqrt{1\cdot 4}+\sqrt{4\cdot 9}+\sqrt{1\cdot 9}$.)
This seems like an almost random sequence of numbers. The OEIS does not have this sequence (but the OEIS has a conjectured sequence of numbers not of the form $ab+bc+ac$).

Edit: Posted on MO.

if $a,b,c$ give $R$ then $2a,2b,2c$ give $2R$, so you can get $R=2^k n$ where $n$ is any odd number greater than $1$. So it's only the powers of $2$ left to worry about.

I have voted to undelete the question with the cited answer. I can understand closing it, but not deleting it after it having received a nice answer. (I'm not saying that because I seem to have played a role in deriving the compact form of the expression for the radius. ... well ... not just because of that. ;)

@Blue: I voted to undelete that linked question. I also did some light editing with the hopeful goal of improving the context and increasing the motivation to undelete.

I've just found $1,4,100$ gives $R=32$, so this and greater powers of $2$ can be made. $1$ and $2$ clearly can't be. So only $4,8,16$ remain open.

@ZoeAllen FYI, $8$ can be constructed by using $a=1$,$b=4$ and $c=4$ as it gives $2+2+4=8$. Thus, $16$ and all higher powers of $2$ can be achieved from that. As for $4$, since each of $\sqrt{ab}$, $\sqrt{bc}$ and $\sqrt{ac}$ must be positive integers (this can be relatively easily proved, and there are also several questions on this site which show it as well), that can only be constructed with $2$ of them being $1$, which requires that $a=b=c=1$, so the third would then be $1$ rather than the required value of $2$ to make a sum of $4$.

Note however that the four inscribed circles exist only if $R$ is greater than $a$, $b$ and $c$.

when $R > \max(a,b,c) $   the missing numbers up to 100   are     1,     2,     4,     7,    13,    14,    17,    23,    28,    34,    37,    43,    46,    49,    53,    67,    73,    97,    98,

I think for any perfect squares a, b and c we can have an integers for R, such as (a ,b ,c, R)=(4, 9, 9, 21), (4, 9, 16, 26), (4, 16, 25, 38), (4, 16, 36, 44)...

@sirous But $R$ must be larger than $a,b,c$ (because the circle with radius $R$ touches all three sides).

@Dan, Do my numbers show that R is not larger than a, b and c?

@sirous In the examples you gave, $R$ is larger than $a,b,c$. But you said that for "any" perfect squares $a,b,c$ we can have an integer $R$. Sometimes this doesn't work, for example $1,1,9$ give $R=1+3+3=7$, which is not larger than $9$.

Don’t we have to include $9$ among the numbers below $100$ that cannot be $R$ values?  For $a, b, c = 1, 1, 16$, $R=9<16$.

@EdwardPorcella $3,3,3$ gives $R=9$, and $9>3$, so $R=9$ is possible.

Thanks, I forgot: if $a=b=c$ they needn’t be square.

@EdwardPorcella If $a=k{n_1}^2,b=k{n_2}^2,c=k{n_3}^2$ where $k,n_1,n_2,n_3\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then $R$ will be an integer (but $R$ might not be greater than $\max(a,b,c)$).

Yes, as long as $ab$, $bc$, $ac$ are square, as in your formulation, then $R$ is an integer.

Hi. Could you please edit the question to clarify what is given and what is not given? For instance do we get to choose a,b,c or are they given? Do we get to choose the triangle or is it given? The current wording of the question is not helpful in that regard.

@Stef You are given an arbitrary positive integer, for example say $923$. Does there exist an arrangement of four integer radii circles and a triangle, as shown in the diagram, such that the largest circle's radius is $923$?

We can say that $R$ is of the form $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ where $a,b,c,R$ are positive integers such that $a\le b\le c\lt R$ if and only if $R$ is of the form $(AB+BC+CA)\color{red}{\times D}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are positive integers such that $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$.
(A proof of this is written at the end of this answer.)
Here, let us call a positive integer $M$ good if $M$ is of the form $(AB+BC+CA)\color{red}{\times 1}$ where $A,B,C$ are positive integers satisfying $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$.
So, we can say the followings :

If $M$ is good, then every multiple of $M$ is our possible $R$.

If at least one divisor of $R$ is good, then $R$ is possible.


(Note that this answer does not say that $R$ is of the form $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ where $a,b,c,R$ are positive integers such that $a\le b\le c\lt R$ if and only if $R$ is good.)
So, when we are given a positive integer, we want to know if it is good.
As you wrote, A025052 shows numbers not of form $ab + bc + ca$ for $1\le a\le b\le c$.
$$1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 18, 22, 30, 42, 58, 70, 78, 102, 130, 190, 210, 330, 462$$
It says "probably the list is complete" and "if the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis is true, then this sequence has no larger terms, otherwise there may be one term greater than $10^{11}$".
Our problem has another condition $C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$, so our problem might be more difficult.
I'll give one way to determine if a given positive integer $M$ is good. (The following way might not be very useful when $M$ is large.)
$M=1,2$ are not good. If $M\ge 3$ is given, then take an integer $B$ satisfying $(\sqrt 2-1)\sqrt{M}\lt B\le\sqrt{M+1}-1$. Then, take an integer $A$ such that $$\frac{\sqrt M(\sqrt M-B)}{\sqrt M+B}\lt A\le\min\bigg(B,\frac{M-B^2}{2B}\bigg)$$ If we can find $(A,B)$ such that $A+B$ divides $M-AB$, then we can conclude that $M$ is good with $C=\frac{M-AB}{A+B}$. Otherwise, we can conclude that $M$ is not good.
Explanations :
From $M=AB+BC+CA$, we have $C=\frac{M-AB}{A+B}$. So, $A,B$ have to satisfy $A\le B\le \frac{M-AB}{A+B}\lt\sqrt{M}$, i.e.
$$A\le B, A\le \frac{M-B^2}{2B},A\gt\frac{\sqrt M(\sqrt M-B)}{\sqrt M+B}$$ Here, it is necessary that $1\le \frac{M-B^2}{2B}$, i.e. $B\le \sqrt{M+1}-1$ with $M\ge 3$. Also, it is necessary that $\frac{\sqrt M(\sqrt M-B)}{\sqrt M+B}\lt B$, i.e. $B\gt (\sqrt 2-1)\sqrt M$.
Examples :

$3$ is good, so every multiple of $3$ is our possible $R$.

$5$ is good, so every multiple of $5$ is our possible $R$.

$8$ is good, so every multiple of $8$ is our possible $R$.

$11$ is good, so every multiple of $11$ is our possible $R$.

$803$ is possible since $803=11\times 73$ has a divisor $11$ which is good.

$71$ is good.(We have $4\le B\le 7$. For $B=5$, we have $3\le A\le 4$. If we take $(A,B)=(3,5)$, then $A+B$ divides $M-AB$, so $C=\frac{M-AB}{A+B}=7$.)

$73$ is not good. (We have $4\le B\le 7$. So, we have $(A,B)=(4,4),(3,5),(4,5),(2,6),(3,6),(1,7)$. However, for every pair, $A+B$ does not divide $M-AB$.)



Finally, let us prove that $R$ is of the form $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ where $a,b,c,R$ are positive integers such that $a\le b\le c\lt R$ if and only if $R$ is of the form $(AB+BC+CA)\color{red}{\times D}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are positive integers such that $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$.
Proof :
(Proof of "only if")
Squaring the both sides $R-\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$, we see that $\sqrt{ab}$ is a rational number, and that $ab$ is a square number. Similarly, $bc,ca$ are square numbers.
Any arbitrary positive integer $n$ can be represented in a unique way as the product of a square $m^2$ and a square-free integer $k$ where $m$ and $k$ are not necessarily coprime. For example, $24=2^2\times 6$.
So, we can write
$$a=A^2D,b=B^2E,c=C^2F$$
where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are positive integers and $D,E,F$ are square-free integers.
We have $\sqrt{ab}=AB\sqrt{DE}$, so $DE$ is a square number. We can see that $p$ is a prime divisor of $D$ if and only if $p$ is a prime divisor of $E$. It follows that $E=D$. Similarly, we have $F=D$.
It follows from $a\le b\le c\lt R=(AB+BC+CA)D$ that
$$A\le B\le C\lt \sqrt{AB+BC+CA}\ .\ \square$$
(Proof of "if")
Let $a:=A^2D,b:=B^2D,c:=C^2D$. Then, $a,b,c$ are positive integer, and  $$R=(AB+BC+CA)D=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$$  It follows from $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$ that
$$a\le b\le c\lt \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}=R.\ \square$$

I. $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}$ is an integer if $a, b, c$ are squares or equi-multiples of squares.
For triads of squares $(a,b,c)$ where $a\le b\le c$, with $c=n^2=1, 4, 9, 16, 25,…$ there are $1, 3, 6, 10, 15,…=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ possible $R$.
E.g. for $c=3^2$ we have six possible triads $$(a,b,c)=(1,1,9), (1,4,9), (1,9,9), (4,4,9), (4,9,9), (9,9,9)$$and$$R=7,11,15,16,21,27$$respectively. Here we see $R<c$ only for triad $(1,1,9)$.
If for a given triad $R<c=n^2$, then $R<c=kn^2$ for positive integer $k$.
Note:

The @Will Jagy list of numbers missing from $R>$ max $(a,b,c)$ contains no $R$ divisible by $3$, since $R=3c$ when $a=b=c$ and $3c>c$.

If an even number is on the list, its half is on the list.

Odd numbers $>1$ on the list are prime or prime-squared ($49$).


II. For $R>c$ from $100-200$, I find missing only$$R=103, 113, 137, 163, 13^2, 193, 197$$for triads$$(9,25,121), (4,49,121), (16,25,169), (a,b,c), (1,81,256), (16,49,225), (1,100,289)$$(I have not found $c$ yielding $R=163$, but since it does not appear for any $c=n^2\le 144$, it too is missing.)
Another square of a prime already on the list of missing ($13$) appears, but no even $R$ doubles of earlier $R<c$: $106=2\cdot 53$; $134=2\cdot 67$; $146=2\cdot 73$; and  $194=2\cdot 97$ first appear as $R>c$.
III. Searching still farther, for $R>c$ from $200-300$, I find missing only$$R=233, 277, 283, 289$$ $R=233$ first appears for triad $(1,144,289$), and $R=283$ for triad $(25,81,289)$. And again, since $R=277$ and $R=289=17^2$ do not appeared through $c=289$, they too are among the missing.
IV. Thus it begins to seem a necessary, though not sufficient, condition of $R<c$ for a given $c=n^2$, that odd $R$ be prime with terminal digit $3$ or $7$, or the square of such a prime.
If this is indeed the case, it would be good to know why.
